# d3 array input line graph example

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json, d3.js

I'm very new to d3 and in order to learn I'm trying to manipulate the [d3.js line example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245),  the code is below. I'm trying to modify this to use model data that I already have on hand. This data is passed down as a json object. The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the data to fit what d3 expects. Most of the d3 examples use key-value arrays. I want to use a key array + a value array. For example my data is structured per the example below:

```
// my data. A name property, with array values and a value property with array values.
// data is the json object returned from the server
var tl   = new Object;
tl.date  = data[0].fields.date;
tl.close = data[0].fields.close;
console.log(tl);
```

Here is the structure visually (yes it time format for now):

[image: My Data]

Now this is different from the [data.tsv](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245#data.tsv) call which results in key-value pairs in the code below.

[image: key-value data]

*The goal is to use my data as is, without having to iterate over my array to preprocess it.*

**Questions:**

1) Are there any built in's to d3 to deal with this situation? For example, if key-values are absolutely necessary in python we could use the `zip` function to quickly generate a key-value list.

2) Can I use my data as is, or does it *have* to be turned into key-value pairs?

**Below is the line example code.**

```
// javascript/d3 (LINE EXAMPLE)
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 640 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {

    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the Object and zip methods in underscore.js library. That should do the trick: [http://underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org)

Comment: A sample of your raw (not screenshot :) tsv data would be helpful.

Comment: @Shahram, I'm trying to not use any more libraries, it's just another dependency to keep track of. I'm hoping d3.js has something already built it for this situation? Besides, I can always hand-jam a javascript iterator to create a new object. Again, the question boils down to: can I do this with the libraries at hand? I.e., jQuery, d3.js...

Comment: @patrickberkeley, I made edits to the body. There is a link for to the raw dataset and example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [d3's array functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays), `zip` is among them.

Here's a commented version of the original gist working with your data: http://bl.ocks.org/patrickberkeley/9162034

The core of it is this:

```
// 1) Zip the close value with their corresponding date/time
//    Results in an array of arrays: 
//
//    [[582.13, "02:30:00"], [583.98, "02:45:00"], ...]
//
data = d3.zip(data.close, data.date).map(function(d) {
  // 2) Format each close and date/time value so d3 understands what each represents.
  close = +d[0];

  // If your data source can't be changed at all, I'd rename `date` to `time` here.
  date = parseTime(d[1]);

  // 3) Return an object for each close and date/time pair.
  return {close: close, date: date};
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the code samples and comments. Very helpful. I think you should include that bit of code in your answer here to help anyone else that comes across this question. I will mark this as the accepted solution as I believe using the native d3 library to perform the json request is probably the better design. Your answer ties with Lars Kotthoff's below. The difference is his solution will allow me to use my arrays as-is (which required a separate ajax call).

Answer (score 2):

You can pass one of your arrays to `.data()` and use the index to get the respective element from the other:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d); })
  .y(function(d, i) { return y(tl.close[i]); });

svg.selectAll("path")
   .data([tl.date])
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("d", line);
```

You just have to remember to set the domains of the scales you're using with the correct arrays.

Comment: Lars thank you for the answer. Your solution allows me to use my arrays as-is which is a good solution. But I have to choose between two answers that are both valid solutions. I wish I could accept both. Instead, I give you a vote and a thank you.